# PHP 5.2.x, monitor a file for changes, native FAM?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a FAM-like solution:

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/fam.installation.php
>
> "This extension is considered unmaintained and dead."

I have a file that's written to randomly, I want to loop and wait for it to change, and then kick off my process.

I don't want to loop fstat sleep if at all possible, fam_next_event blocked until updates and spoiled me. Since FAM isn't in PHP >= 5.0.5 and I don't really want to rely on something that's no longer maintained, I'm hoping someone has done something similar.

Is there a FAM replacement? Something better/native?

Comment: Do the inotify functions help? http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.inotify.php

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the Inotify extension could fullfill your needs

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.inotify.php

have a look at it.